# Javascript: Where do I put an array with standard data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a bit new to posting here, I've always found my answers by searching and never needed to create my own post, so if I'm doing something wrong please do tell me.

I also don't really know how to formulate the question, so I'm sorry if it's weird.

I'm writing an extension for chrome and I'm unsure about where I leave my array with country codes and names.

Right now it's just at the start of my javascript file (with all the other code under it). It's not really a problem but I feel like I can put it somewhere else. Should I make a seperate file for it or should I leave it the way it is?

It's just this:

```
var countryList = [
    ["AF", "Afghanistan"],
    ["AX", "Aland Islands"],
    ["AL", "Albania"],
    ["DZ", "Algeria"],
    ["AS", "American Samoa"],
    ["AD", "Andorra"],
    ["AO", "Angola"],
    ["AI", "Anguilla"],
    ["AQ", "Antarctica"],
    ["AG", "Antigua And Barbuda"],
    ["AR", "Argentina"],
    ["AM", "Armenia"],
    // And then a whole bunch more...
];
```

I'm sure I can find the answer somewhere, but since I'm having trouble formulating it I can't seem to find any related issues.

Comment: It is just a personal reference. If there is not really a need to remove it into a separate file, for example using it like a library or global function, just leave it at the top of the code where you would normally define global properties.

Comment: As this list looks to be quite big, putting it in another file is probably the best option. Plus you're writing an extension, it doesn't sound like you'll need to worry about the overhead of an extra request.

Comment: I'd say it depends on how large the data array is. It would certainly be cleaner to move it in its own json file, but only you decide what level of cleanliness your source requires.

Comment: wouldn't an associative array being more appropriate here?

Comment: @kasperTaeymans Yeah that's indeed easier. I'll use that instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best practice to put it either in a namespace or scoped within another function to keep it out of the Global namespace of the 'Window' object and not have any potential conflicts with other variables/libraries.

Here's an example of a namespace:

```
var App = {
    countryList: []
};

var arr = App.countryList[0];
```

Here's an example of scoping:

```
(function() {
    var countryList = [];

    // do something here
})();
```

When scoping within a Function like the last example, the 'countryList' variable will only be available to other functions/code contained within the surrounding function. By the way, this is scoped/contained it within an "anonymous method" that is automatically executed after declaration, via currying.

More information about Currying: http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/